# After Submit the Form data, success message display on redirected Page

Tags: php, html

i am using Localhost using xamp, i have created html,css3 form and also create a php script file but when i click on form submit button the data is send to database but the form current page is redirect to connect.php and also the message "New record is inserted successfully" displayed on redirected page.

While i want to display the "**New record is inserted successfully**" message on same page and also do not want the redirection.

my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Form site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="connect.php">
        <!-- Existing fields -->
        Cnic: <input type="number" name="cnic_number"><br><br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        FIR No: <input type="text" name="fir_no"><br><br>
        FIR Date: <input type="date" name="fir_date"><br><br>
        Section: <input type="text" name="section"><br><br>
        Police Station: <input type="text" name="police_station"><br><br>
        Address: <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <!-- Placeholder for success message -->
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$cnic_number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cnic_number');
$fir_no = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fir_no');
$fir_date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fir_date');
$section = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'section');
$police_station = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'police_station');
$address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address');

if (!empty($name) && !empty($cnic_number)) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "mysite2";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        // Prepare and execute the SQL query to insert data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mysite2table (name, cnic_number, fir_no, fir_date, section, police_station, address)
                VALUES ('$name', '$cnic_number', '$fir_no', '$fir_date', '$section', '$police_station', '$address')";

        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
            echo "New record is inserted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . " " . $conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
} else {
    echo "cnic number and name should not be empty";
}
?>
```

Check the screenshot when i submit the data

[image: when entering the data]

After submitting the page is redirected to connect.php and message also displayed on redirected page

[image]

My PC folder screenshot

[image]

**Note:** I want to display the message "**New record is inserted successfully**" on same page "**form.html**" and also do not want the page to be redirected to connect.php

I hope someone will help me, because i am stuck here and i am giving up

Comment: You need to use AJAX if you don't want form submission to reload the page.

Comment: @Barmar kindly share code with me, how to use ajax here, i will appreciate your work,

Comment: just merge the two files you posted

Comment: **Warning!** You're open to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)! Read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) by using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your queries. The `filter_input()`-function isn't just old, but it doesn't protect against SQL injections at all and shouldn't be used for anything.

Comment: _"kindly share code with me, how to use ajax here"_ - Google "get started with Ajax" and you will find many many tutorials. I recommend reading those that uses the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Asking us to write your code for you, or write a tutorial is off-topic here.

Comment: A whole subject like AJAX can't be taught in a SO answer.

Comment: And even if we "share code" with your you probably wouldn't understand it or be able to use it effectively. So please go and learn the basic concepts of ajax, so that you do. Then have a go at solving this yourself based on your new knowledge. If you're still stuck after that, and found a specific problem in your attempted code, that would be a good question to ask us later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters suggested, you should really read up on AJAX request, to be able to effectively use them. Here's however some basic code that should get you started.

First off we want to keep the form from actually submitting but calling a javascript function instead:

```
<form method="post" action="connect.php" onsubmit="mySubmitForm(this, 'message'); return false;">
```

So when the user submits the form the function `mySubmitForm` is being called and by returning `false` the form will not get submitted by the browser.

Then we need a javascript function that takes all the values from the form, submits them in an AJAX request to the URL given in the `action` attribute of your form and then displays the results to the user:

```
async function mySubmitForm(form, result_container) {
    fetch(form.getAttribute('action'),
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(form)
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => document.getElementById(result_container).innerHTML = text)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

And that's pretty much it. Your complete *form.html* would then look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Form site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="connect.php" onsubmit="mySubmitForm(this, 'message'); return false;">
        <!-- Existing fields -->
        Cnic: <input type="number" name="cnic_number"><br><br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        FIR No: <input type="text" name="fir_no"><br><br>
        FIR Date: <input type="date" name="fir_date"><br><br>
        Section: <input type="text" name="section"><br><br>
        Police Station: <input type="text" name="police_station"><br><br>
        Address: <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <!-- Placeholder for success message -->
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
        async function mySubmitForm(form, result_container) {
            fetch(form.getAttribute('action'),
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: new FormData(form)
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => document.getElementById(result_container).innerHTML = text)
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bundles of Thanks @volkerschulz you did a great job, i was stuck but your code is awesome and it worked for me,

Comment: i accepted the answer thanks

Answer (score -1):

After statement, before closing your php tag, put this line

```
header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/');
```

Sometime, your destination can be inside your website, in this case, use

```
header('Location: ../folder/file.ext');
```

where ../folder/file.ext is your path

If you have many redirection to do, create a function

```
function redirect($path){

    header('Location: ' . $path);
}
```

Header take a lot parameters... This is not a complete explanation.

To display your message after redirecting, put your message in session. Don't forget to start it.

```
$_SESSION['message'] = $message; // to add your value
```

and

```
echo "Your form was submitted successfully. Specific message : " . $_SESSION['message']; // to get your value
```

Comment: This is definitely **not** best practice. It is substituting one redirect (that the OP didn't want) by **two** redirects. **If** you wanna go that route, use `header` right after the opening tag, so it doesn't break if errors occur. And please don't use sessions to transport error messages. If the file containing the form was a PHP file anyways, one would do the processing there instead of redirecting back and fort. And all that wouldn't even be necessary if using AJAX, what would be the best way to go here.